# unable to display background color in activity

Tags: android, xml

this is my `XML` file. I am having trouble while running my app. I have already created same GUI for registration activity but getting problem while designing login activity. I have declared `tools:background = "@color/colorPrimary"` but unable get colorPrimary . what should I do to solve this error. why I am getting this error. Help me.

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:background="@color/colorPrimary"
tools:context="com.example.pratikrathi.registerapp.RegisterActivity">
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/reg_email_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="54dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/email_hint"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:paddingVertical="16dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/whiteTransparentHalf"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/login_progress" />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/reg_password_text"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    android:ems="10"
    android:hint="@string/password_hint"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:paddingVertical="16dp"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textColorHint="@color/whiteTransparentHalf"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reg_email_text" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/colorAccent"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/login_btn_text"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/reg_password_text" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/login_reg_btn"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@android:color/white"
    android:paddingBottom="20dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp"
    android:text="@string/login_reg_btn_text"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/login_progress"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:indeterminate="true"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
 </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: try : `android:background="@color/colorPrimary"`

Comment: Use android:background="@color/colorPrimary", it may help you

Comment: yeah that was too easy. thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply change `tools:background="@color/colorPrimary"` to `android:background="@color/colorPrimary"`,

since tools is used for visibility inside android studio in preview

Answer (score 0):

add following code, where you want to apply backgroung:

```
style="@style/style1"
```

**values/style.xml**

```
<style name="style1">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_color</item>
</style>
```

**drawable\custom_color.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <shape>
        <solid android:color="@color/custom_color" />
    </shape>
</item>
```

**values\colors.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<color name="custom_color">#123456</color>
</resources>
```